# currency convertor webservice doesnot work in web application

Tags: web-services, wsdl2java

I am trying to configure "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx" web service in my web application. I generated java client classes using wsdl2java provided with Axis2.
Standalone java program works fine.

```
 public double convertINRtoUSD(double inr) throws AxisFault, RemoteException{

    //double inr  = 10000;
   // double rate = conversionRate( Currency.INR,Currency.USD); 

    CurrencyConvertorCurrencyConvertorSoapStub stub=
     new CurrencyConvertorCurrencyConvertorSoapStub();

    ConversionRate cr = new ConversionRate();

    cr.setToCurrency(Currency.INR);

    cr.setFromCurrency(Currency.USD);


    ConversionRateResponse response =stub.conversionRate(cr);

    double d= inr/response.getConversionRateResult();
    System.out.printf( "USD for %f INR = %f\n", inr, d);
    return d;

  }
```

but when i use same piece of code in web application. it throws Axisfault   exception.
please suggest.
here is the exception:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$LocalVariableTableVisitor.resolveMember(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:236)
at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$LocalVariableTableVisitor.visitEnd(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:219)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: let me know if my query doesnot look clear.

Comment: Your question is missing the most important part: the stacktrace of the exception. Add that to your question or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: If anybody can guide me to use currencyconverter web service             "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx" in struts application ,that will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some JAR files. If I'm not mistaken its the `axis2-kernel` jar.

You have to add it to your project.

You can get the JAR from the [Axis2 distribution](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi) or [from Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2) if you have that kind of build process.